# Coletar nome da categoria WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou tentando coletar o nome da categoria com o seguinte código

```
<a href="<?php get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?>"></a>
```

Porem não estou tendo muito sucesso.. outra coisa é, eu tenho umas 4 categorias porem o código precisa saber se esta utilizando categoria a ou b dentro das 4, se não tiver nenhuma categoria que seja a A ou a B não mostra nada.. se alguém puder me ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A função `get_cat_name` retorna uma string [como informado na documentação](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_name/), e em sua linha onde você coloca a tag `a` você não esta usando o `echo` nem `<?=` para exibir o nome.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?>"></a>
```

OU

```
<a href="<?= get_cat_name( $cat_id ); ?>"></a>
```

Com relação a verificação você pode fazer um simples `if`

```
<a href="<? echo (get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == 'a' || get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == 'b') ? 'exibe o resultado' : ''; ?>"></a>
```

***Substitua o `"exibe o resultado"` pelo resultado que você quer que apareça caso a categoria a ou categoria b exista***

Comment: Olá Rafael, obrigado pela ajuda, usei o codigo porem não funcionou:  >> <a href="<? echo (get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == '48' || get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == '49') ? 'exibe o resultado' : ''; ?>"></a>

Comment: que erro deu @RenatoAssis?

Comment: Não funcionou @RafaelAcioly

Comment: @RenatoAssis como você colocou o código?

Comment: da mesma forma que você vê acima > <a href="<? echo (get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == '48' || get_cat_name( $cat_id ) == '49') ? 'exibe o resultado' : ''; ?>"></a>

Comment: @RenatoAssis sugiro que você estudo um pouco mais de `PHP` para prosseguir com o uso do `wordpress` sem dor de cabeça, alterei a resposta para que fique mais claro.

Comment: Eu não entendo de PHP mais vou me virando das formas que consigo... vc não entendeu muito bem o que eu quero, não preciso exibir um resultado especifico preciso que exiba apenas o nome da categoria.. se for A exibe o nome A se for B exibe o nome B, se não for A nem B não exibe nada.. nada mais que isso se puder ajudar fico grato.

Comment: Entendo que o exibir resultado seria o ideal inserir a função que informa o nome da categoria, mais é ai que eu não consigo.. não sei a função que vai fazer isso.. já tentei de todas as formas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53568/discussion-between-renato-assis-and-rafael-acioly).

Comment: Poderia passar mais informações? - @RafaelAcioly